# How to match most non-digits using regex?

Tags: javascript, python, regex, perl

I want to replace all non-digit characters from a string except for a leading minus sign (`-`).

For example, `hu` should be removed from `-123hu8`, and `-jk` should be removed from `34-jk8`.

I'm using the following regex, but it doesn't work.

```
^[^-]|[^\d\.]
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: share your code

Comment: Also, pick a language. JavaScript, Python, and Perl have different regex engines and support different features.

Comment: I assume by `characters` you mean `alphabetic characters`?

Comment: What about `-123hu-8`? Would this replace just `hu` or `hu-`?

Comment: it will replace hu-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not the start of the string followed by a hyphen.

Then match an optional hyphen followed by 1+ times not a digit.

```
(?!^-)\D+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?!^-)` Negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), assert what is directly on the right is not the start of the string followed by a hyphen
- `\D+` Match 1+ times not a digit

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QWmWFq/1/)

Or to match word characters without a digit you could use:

```
(?!^-)[^\W\d]+
```

The last part in this pattern:

- `[^\W\d]+` Negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match a word character except the digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y02o8r/1)

Comment: Can you edit my regrex to meet my requirement as i find it difficult to understand your regex although it works

Comment: @HarisMuzaffar I have added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Got it! But (?!^-)-?\D+ will even if we remove -? i.e (?!^-)\D+ will work perfectly because what i want here is to replace all characters except digits from the source string but dont replace the starting minus sign.

Answer (score 2):

Because look-arounds are expensive,

```
(?!^-)\D+
```

is probably slower than

```
(?:^-?+|\d++)\K\D+
```

I don't know if that matters to you.

Test:

```
>perl -e"CORE::say $ARGV[0] =~ s/(?:^-?+|\d++)\K\D+//rg;" -- -123hu8
-1238

>perl -e"CORE::say $ARGV[0] =~ s/(?:^-?+|\d++)\K\D+//rg;" -- 123hu8
1238

>perl -e"CORE::say $ARGV[0] =~ s/(?:^-?+|\d++)\K\D+//rg;" -- a123hu8
1238

>perl -e"CORE::say $ARGV[0] =~ s/(?:^-?+|\d++)\K\D+//rg;" -- -a123hu8
-1238

>perl -e"CORE::say $ARGV[0] =~ s/(?:^-?+|\d++)\K\D+//rg;" -- 34-jk8
348
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `^[^-]|[^\d\.]`

Support for character classes (like `\d`) inside of classes isn't implemented in some languages. What language are you using? You might have better luck with `[^0-9\.]`.

You have `^[^-]` which matches any string that doesn't start with `-`, which includes digits, so the first digit of a number would be squashed. You want to replace `-` only when it is not followed by a digit.

Note that your expression matches only one character, so you would need to recursively apply it to modify the whole string. Or you can use '+' or '*' to match multiple characters. We might be able to help you better if you include a few lines of code where this is used.

Conceptually it would be simpler to extract the number part and throw away the rest of the string, but it sounds like you want `34-jk8` to turn into `348`. How would you handle a leading `-` such as `-jk348`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$_='-123hu8-34-jk8'
s/[^\d-]+//g
print $_
```

gnu sed

```
echo '-123hu8-34-jk8'| sed -E 's/[^-0-9]//g'
```

Comment: Adding a brief explanation will help others understand your solution.